# Agregar icono a listview se cierra la aplicación

Tags: android, listview

> Cuando le trato de agregar la imagen a la *listview* como icono de los ítems, es donde truena, le quito la imagen y ya corre todo bien.

Tengo una *listview* con librería *volley*, y al agregarle un icono general para todos los ítems me truena la aplicación.

Aquí les dejo los códigos:

```
    String url = "URL.com";
    ProgressDialog PD;

    ArrayList<String> countries;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccionarvehiculo);
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        countries=new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.items, R.id.tv, countries);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //countries = new ArrayList<String>();

        PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
        PD.setMessage("Loading.....");
        PD.setCancelable(false);

        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.items, R.id.tv, countries);
        //setListAdapter(adapter);

        MakeJsonArrayReq();
    }

    private void MakeJsonArrayReq() {
        PD.show();

        JsonArrayRequest jreq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = jo.getString("objectno");
                                countries.add(name);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        PD.dismiss();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jreq, "jreq");
    }

public void buttonClick(View view){
    Intent mintent = new Intent(seleccionarvehiculo.this, Main22Activity.class);
    startActivity(mintent);
}

}
```

Código de *layout*:

```
<Button
    android:text="Seleccionar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/inroutenumerovehiculos"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="229dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />
```

Aquí el código que genera los ítems:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. _Me truena la aplicación_ no es una excelente descripción de lo que pasa.  Sugeriría que si tienes una versión que corre y una que no, restaltes que es lo que cambia entre una y otra. También es buena idea que agregues la información relevante del LOG.

Comment: Cuando le trato de agregar la imagen a la listview como icono de los itens es donde truena, le quito la imagen y ya corre todo bien

Comment: El layout de cada item esta completo? porque si es asi la aplicacion se cae debido a que no tienes un ImageView dentro del layout solo tienes un textview.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de lo que agregas  y falla? Si eres programador android es importante el LogCat. =)

Comment: Podrias agregar el logcat del error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada, te recomiendo que uses *RecyclerView*, ya que *ListView* no se usa más. Te recomiendo este Post que es muy bueno.

http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/

Con *RecyclerView* se te solucionan todos tus problemas, estoy más que seguro.

Por otro lado- 
- respondiendo a tu pregunta, revisa que en la lista no venga algún objeto nulo.
- en el Layout que genera los items no veo que tengas un ImageView, debería qeudar así:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        />
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src = "@drawable/my_image_view"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Salu2

Comment: Gracias era un problema de parametro del tamaño de la imagen ya lo solucione, muchas gracias